# Storm : NettyRenameThreadFactory. Why Storm need to rename thread names

Tags: java, multithreading, netty, apache-storm

I am looking through Storm's source code especially messaging module, I came to `NettyRenameThreadFactory`. I don't quite understand why Storm need to rename thread names, what is underlying reason to do this? 
Here is the class, I also don't understand well the usage of `ThreadNameDeterminer.CURRENT`.

```
  public class NettyRenameThreadFactory  implements ThreadFactory {

  static {
  //Rename Netty threads
   ThreadRenamingRunnable.setThreadNameDeterminer(ThreadNameDeterminer.CURRENT);
  }

  final ThreadGroup group;
  final AtomicInteger index = new AtomicInteger(1);
  final String name;

  NettyRenameThreadFactory(String name) {
    SecurityManager s = System.getSecurityManager();
    group = (s != null)? s.getThreadGroup() :
                         Thread.currentThread().getThreadGroup();
    this.name = name;
  }

  public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
    Thread t = new Thread(group, r, name + "-" + index.getAndIncrement(), 0);
    if (t.isDaemon())
        t.setDaemon(false);
    if (t.getPriority() != Thread.NORM_PRIORITY)
        t.setPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY);
    return t;
  }
}
```

Comment: This question is very specific. Not sure if you will get an answer here. I would ask at dev mailing list.

Comment: It's just a convenience when debugging, so that know at a glance which threads belong to which pool. It would continue to work if the threads were not renamed.